# Why Gradle build is very slow for Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, build

Android Studio is the latest IDE for Android development. I'm OK with change in IDE although it takes time getting used to, unlike eclipse which was swift and easy. Then when you start using Android Studio first thing you notice is that build system is mind blowingly slow, you can get a coffee drink it and still keep starring at the screen, and it's still building for a big project. I don't understand fully why does it take so much time to just build apk unlike eclipse used to do within minutes, and this one takes several minutes. So I would like to understand, why does it take so much time to build, and what are the elements that are considered for Gradle that make it so slow?

Comment: Gradle is actually pretty fast if configured properly, and it can get really slow if configured poorly. If you intend to receive tips on how to fix your build setup to make it faster - you'll need to post your build.gradle file and describe your project structure.

Comment: You may also want to watch the ["What's New in Android Development Tools" video from Google I|O 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ihSQ44WO0), where they discuss why the builds are slow and what is being done to improve matters in the coming months.